# Módulo para Node Js que captura informações do Sistema Operacional e do computador

Tags: node.js

Como obter usando Node Js o uso do processamento, memória, load average e informações do sistema operacional?

Sei que em Java, por exemplo, existe a biblioteca "OperatingSystemMXBean" gostaria de uma equivalente.

O módulo nativo ['os'](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) é uma boa opção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com o módulo os você consegue obter as informações de CPU e memória:

```
const os = require('os');

console.log(os.cpus());
console.log(os.totalmem());
console.log(os.freemem())
```

O Módulo [os-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-utils) também é interessante, funciona mais ou menos da mesma maneira:

```
const os = require('os-utils');

os.cpuUsage(function(v){
    console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v );
});
```

Informações de uso de disco você pode usar o [diskspace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskspace):

```
const diskspace = require('diskspace');

diskspace.check('C', function (err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
});
```